# Can we prove that $0$ is an eigenvalue of this matrix without computing its characteristic polynomial?

Tags: linear-algebra

Without calculating the characteristic polynomial, can we say that $0$ is eigenvalue of the following matrix?

$$
\begin{bmatrix}0&1&0&1\\-3&0&0&0\\0&1&0&1\\0&0&0&0\end{bmatrix}
$$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. This matrix has a row of zeros and therefore has determinant zero. Since the determinant is the product of the eigenvalues it follows that zero is an eigenvalue of this matrix.

Alternatively we can note that $A\vec x=\vec 0$ where
$$
\vec x=\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\0\\-1\end{bmatrix}
$$
That is, $A\vec x=0\cdot\vec x$ so $0$ is indeed an eigenvalue.

Comment: So, if I find a solution $(x,y,z,t)$ for the following equation it means that $0$ is an eigenvalue of the matrix? $$
\begin{bmatrix}0&1&0&1\\-3&0&0&0\\0&1&0&1\\0&0&0&0\end{bmatrix} * \begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\z\\t\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: @user254322 Yes absolutely.

Comment: @MathLearner It has to be a **nonzero** solution to that equation.

Answer (score 1):

Or another way is to see that it has rank at most 3 so has nullity at least 1, and hence has non-trivial null space . Hence there is an $0 \neq v\in \Bbb{R^4}$ such that $Av=0$

Answer (score 0):

As someone said the matrix has one zero row, but also the zero column, which is enough to conclude that the column rank can't be full, and the column rank is equal to the row rank and if it is smaller than the matrix dimension it can not be invertible.

Another observation is the duplicate columns $$\left(\begin{array}{c}1\\0\\1\\0\end{array}\right)$$ which ensure that the column rank must be at least 1 less once again. Also two rows are $$\left(\begin{array}{cccc}0&1&0&1\end{array}\right)$$ which guarantee the same about the row rank.